# How to save multiple values from select2_from_ajax_multiple in Backpack laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

everyone

I am tring to save the Multiple values from select option, but i don't have knowledge about how to save in laravel **Backpack** .I have been trying to solve the error from 2 days, but still it's not working from my side.

Please have a look, help would be appreciated.
Here is Screen shot of multiple select option --- [image]

But it does not saving in db, but if i am going to edit the record , it gives this error --- [image]

**Here is my controller code**

```
CRUD::addField([ // select2_from_ajax: 1-n relationship
      'label'                => "City Name", // Table column heading
      'type'                 => 'select2_from_ajax_multiple',
      'name'                 => 'location_id', // the column that contains the ID of that connected entity;
      'entity'               => 'location', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
      'attribute'            => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
      'tab'                  => 'Texts',
      'data_source'          => url('api/location'), // url to controller search function (with /{id} should return model)
      'placeholder'          => 'Select location', // placeholder for the select
      'include_all_form_fields' => true, //sends the other form fields along with the request so it can be filtered.
         'minimum_input_length' => 0, // minimum characters to type before querying results
      'dependencies'         => ['state'], // when a dependency changes, this select2 is reset to null
      // 'method'                    => 'GET', // optional - HTTP method to use for the AJAX call (GET, POST)
      "allows_multiple" => true,
      'pivot' => true,
]);
```

Comment: you are using 'pivot' => true, this option for many to many relation, are you sure that the 'location' relation is belongsToMany?

Comment: I already tried withiout pivot. Nothing worked, now using pivot, it's still not working. Also, i don't have prior knowledge of Backpack framework, how to svae things, I know laravel, but it's different

Comment: it would be helpful if you share both models

Comment: Ok, here is Service model --- https://pastebin.com/s9GGy1fm
Location model --- https://pastebin.com/QFb49aDQ

Comment: both linked cant be reached!

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: please share codes not images